Cell diagrams of projective resolutions
A really nice way to visualize resolutions of modules over small algebras is through cell diagrams. These are really useful, for instance, in algebraic topology, when one wants to compute Ext over a small sub-Hopf algebra of the Steenrod algebra. I think Adams uses this visualization in naming certain modules "lightning flash modules". This paper has a bunch of great pictures. I've inserted an example from it.
My question: how does one actually make these in LaTeX? I would imagine it is in TikZ but I am not sure.

One idea is to use the Matrix library to place points in nodes. Then draw paths through these nodes.

Source for the linked paper, including TikZ for the figures is available at https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.07530, although the license doesn't allow for their direct reproduction here.

@DaiBowen Wow, did not realize you could do that. feelin foolish. thanks!

Some help for you to get started.
1) Making things work
Following Dai Bowen's suggestion you can download TeX-sources there. Once you unpacked them you see a number of files, where the master is the main document:

The drawings you have in mind are in file cbms-examples.tex. If you look through it, you'll see tikzpicture environments, like this one, embedded in regular LaTeX:

To work with those codes, copy them and put them in a new file, like exmpl-1.tex; remarks:

class standalone makes your life with drawings easier
leaving out the \input line results in compile errors, because ...
cbms-preamble.tex holds macros used here
so either input it (on the expense of installing missing packages) OR ...
copy just all statements like these into exmpl-1.tex BEFORE \begin{document}

%%%%
\def\sqtwoL (#1,#2,#3){
  \draw[#3] (#1,#2) .. controls (#1-1,#2+1) .. (#1,#2+2);
}

\def\sqtwoR (#1,#2,#3){
  \draw[#3] (#1,#2) .. controls (#1+1,#2+1) .. (#1,#2+2);
}
...


the two grids just shall help you locating coordinates more easily
the rest is just the copy from aboves code lines (108 ff.)


\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\input{cbms-preamble}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=.5]     % not needed with standalone
 \draw[teal!30] (0,0) grid (4,10);
 \draw[orange!30] (0,0) grid (-4,10);
 
  \fill (-4, 1) circle (3pt);
  \sqtwoL(-4,1,black);
  \fill (-4, 3) circle (3pt);
  \sqone(-4,3,black)
  \fill (-4, 4) circle (3pt);

  \fill (0, 0) circle (3pt);
  \fill (0, 1) circle (3pt);
  \fill (0, 2) circle (3pt);
  \fill (0, 3) circle (3pt);
  \fill (0, 4) circle (3pt);
  \fill (0, 5) circle (3pt);
  \fill (0, 6) circle (3pt);
  \fill (0, 7) circle (3pt);
  \fill (0, 8) circle (3pt);
  \fill (0, 9) circle (3pt); 
  \fill (2, 3) circle (3pt);
  \fill (2, 4) circle (3pt);
  \sqone (0, 0, black);
  \sqtwoL (0, 0, black);
  \sqone (0, 2, black);
  \sqtwoL (0, 3, black);
  \sqone (0, 4, black);
  \sqtwoR (0, 4, black);
  \sqone (0, 6, black);
  \sqtwoR (0, 7, black);
  \sqone (0, 8, black); 
  \sqtwoCR (0, 1, black);
  
    \sqtwoCR (0, 2, black);
  \sqone (2, 3, black);
  
    \foreach \y in {0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,9}
           {\fill (4, \y) circle (3pt);}
           \sqtwoL (4, 0,black);
           \sqtwoL (4, 3, black);
           \sqtwoR (4, 4, black);
           \sqtwoR (4, 7, black);
           \sqone (4, 2, black);
           \sqone (4,4, black);
           \sqone (4,6, black); 
             \sqone (4,8, black); 
  

   \draw[blue,->] (-4, 1) .. controls (-2, 0.75) ..  (0, 1);
     \draw[blue,->] (-4, 3)  .. controls (-1, 2.5) ..  (2, 3); 
          \draw[blue,->] (-4, 4) .. controls (-1, 3.5) .. (2, 4); 

  
  \node[anchor=north] at (-4,0.5) {$Q$};
    \node[anchor=north] at (0,-0.5) {$R_3$};
        \node[anchor=north] at (4,-0.5) {$M_{\infty}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

2) Code review
As you can see, the design follows a regular grid, just like you would draw on similar paper at school.
Defining macros \sqtwoL etc. is a good idea wrt consistent shorthand notations. However, the dots should have been absorbed by a macro, too, instead of repeating \fill (-4, 1) circle (3pt); all over.
A more experienced TikZ user would delegate all those dot-placements to 1 or 2 \foreach loops.
Same for the bent interconnects via \sqtwoL etc.
A more experienced TikZ user would also recognize style-worthy parts like:
NOW:
  \node[anchor=north] at (-4,0.5) {$Q$};
    \node[anchor=north] at (0,-0.5) {$R_3$};
        \node[anchor=north] at (4,-0.5) {$M_{\infty}$};

THEN :
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   an/.style={anchor=north},
]
...
\node[an] at (-4, 0.5) {$Q$};
\node[an] at ( 0,-0.5) {$R_3$};
\node[an] at ( 4,-0.5) {$M_{\infty}$};
...

Overall I think this code can be done simpler and more consistently, when taking the other drawing not shown into account (i.e. the variability/flexibility you need).

thank you for this response!! This is exactly the level of detail I needed.
